# algorithm for checking close by numbers for similarities in a list

Tags: algorithm, list

I have a list and I need to find and extract all numbers in close proximity to a new list.

for example I have a list:

1,5,10,8,11,14,15,11,14,1,4,7,5,9

so if I want to extract all numbers that are close by 3(only 3, the gap must be 3, so 11,14 is correct, 11,13 is not.) near each other how can I design this without hard-coding the whole thing?

the result should look like:
8,11,14,11,14,1,4,7

This doesn't look too hard ,but I'm kind stuck, all I can come up with is a loop that checks n+1 member of the loop if it's more than n by 3 and include the n+1 member in a new list, however I don't know how to include the n member without making it appear on the new list twice if there is a string of needed numbers.

any ideas?

Comment: It might be worth showing what you have tried. Do you mind what language the solution is in?

Comment: i don't get your question, why is "1" in the output?

Comment: I don't get it either, why isn't 15 in the output list?

Comment: 1 is the output because it has a neighbor that is is close by 3 near him. Basically there is a list, need to extract chains of numbers that increase by 3 with every step, chains in the example: 8,11,14 ; 11,14; 1,4,7 all increase by 3 per new position.

Comment: oh sorry, 15 isn't in the least because the gap needs to be exactly 3, will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the list, checking the next and previous element, and save the current one if it differs by 3 from either one. In Python, that's

```
>>> l = [1,5,10,8,11,14,15,11,14,1,4,7,5,9]
>>> # pad with infinities to ease the final loop
>>> l = [float('-inf')] + l + [float('inf')]
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(l[1:-1], 1)
...  if 3 in (abs(x - l[i-1]), abs(x - l[i+1]))]
[8, 11, 14, 11, 14, 1, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab

```
list = [1,5,10,8,11,14,15,11,14,1,4,7,5,9]
```

then

```
list(or([diff([0 diff(list)==3]) 0],[0 diff(list)==3]))
```

returns

```
8    11    14    11    14     1     4     7
```

For those who don't understand Matlab `diff(list)` returns the first (forward) differences of the elements in `list`.  The expression `[0 diff(list)]` pads the first differences with a leading `0` to make the result the same length as the original `list`.  The rest should be obvious.

In a nutshell: take forward differences and backward differences, select the elements where either difference is `3`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple C++ code below:

assuming `ar` is the array of the initial integers and mark is a `boolean array`

```
for(int i=1;i<N;i++){
     if(ar[i]-ar[i-1]==3){
         mark[i]=1;
         mark[i-1]=1;
     }
}
```

Now to print the interesting numbers,

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    if(mark[i]==1)cout<<ar[i]<<" ";
}
```

The idea behind the implementation is, we mark a number as interesting if the difference from it to its previous one is 3 or if the difference between it and its next number is 3.

Answer (score 0):

that's a single loop:

```
public List<int> CloseByN(int n, List<int> oldL)
{
   bool first = true;
   int last = 0;
   bool isLstAdded = false;
   List<int> newL = new List<int>();
   foreach(int curr in oldL)
   {
      if(first)
      {
         first = false;
         last = curr;
         continue;
      }
      if(curr - last == n)
      {
         if(isLstAdded == false)
         {
           newL.Add(last);
           isLstAdded = true;
         }
         newL.Add(curr);
      }
      else
      {
         isLstAdded = false;
      }
      last = curr;
   }
   return newL;
}
```

tested on your input and got your output

Answer (score 0):

And a Haskell version:

```
f g xs = dropWhile (null . drop 1) $ foldr comb [[last xs]] (init xs) where
  comb a bbs@(b:bs) 
    | abs (a - head b) == g = (a:head bbs) : bs
    | otherwise = 
        if null (drop 1 b) then [a] : bs else [a] : bbs
```

Output:

```
*Main> f 3 [5,10,8,11,14,15,11,14,1,4,7,5,9]
[[8,11,14],[11,14],[1,4,7]]

*Main> f 5 [5,10,8,11,14,15,11,14,1,4,7,5,9]
[[5,10]]
```